# Combine multiple ListView scroll as one in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, nestedscrollview

I have a simple ListView with a scrollable child, which works as it should. But the issue is, when I scroll the items of ScrollableChild and it reaches its last child, it doesn't scroll the parent ListView. How can I achieve this behaviour?

```
ListView(children: [
    ...items(5),
    ScrollableChild(),
    ...items(30),
  ])
```

I have tried to use the NestedScrollableWidget but unable to find any working solution.

[Sample Code](https://dartpad.dev/b79a57ede8fad24b41c9397850164b17)

I've tried to use the CustomScrollView, but unfortunately, the result is the same.

```
CustomScrollView(slivers: [
    SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(items(5))),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ScrollableChild()),
    SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(items(50))),
  ]),
```

[Sample Code](https://dartpad.dev/e025ccf048aef871c7b79b9992459347)

The expected behavior can be viewed in this [[Video]](https://streamable.com/d9d64z).
the code I have shared works fine in a browser without any issue if you scroll it using the mouse wheel only.
When the blue child items scroll reaches at the end. it just scrolls the parent, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: use `CustomScrollView` with multiple `SliverList`s as `slivers:`

Comment: I am avoiding `CustomScrollView`. any other solution brother?

Comment: no, no any other solutions

Comment: consider using .map... i have achieved something like this with that

Comment: can you provide any example?

Comment: `CustomScrollView(slivers: [SliverList(...), SliverList(...), SliverList(...)])`

Comment: hello @pskink, I've tried to use the `customScrollView` but unfortunately, the result is the same. Please take a look at the sample code if I am missing something?

Comment: `CustomScrollView(slivers: [
SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(items(5))),
SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(height: 1000, color: Colors.red)),
SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(items(50))),
]),`

Comment: @pskink, your sample code will work fine for a simple static child, but the problem is I have a fairly complex child widget that is scrollable and not editable. what should I do for that case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232473/discussion-between-towhid-and-pskink).